# How to initialize a Custom type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a custom data type

```
type GrpcReturnType ={data: string,error :grpcWeb.RpcError}
```

I get the following error if I do not initialize it in  the constructor  `Property 'responseData' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)`

But if I try to initialize it in the ctor

```
  constructor() {
   this.responseData.data =""
  }
```

I get the error `'responseData' is used before being assigned.ts(2565)`

What is the syntax to initialize a custom type in TypeScript

Answer (score 0):

Using this format

```
  constructor() {
   this.responseData = <GrpcReturnType>{}
   this.responseData.data =""

  }
```